# Will Magento 2 be included in next year Magento developers' certification?

Tags: magento2, certification

I'm going to take the test next year (2016) and I know that Magento 2 is going to be released. Is there any information about next year's quiz? Will there have Magento 2? And where can i find quizzes (like the original ones) to practice?

Answer (score 4):

I mailed the Magento Team in June'15 to tell whether or not i should sit for Magento Certification somewhere in months July-'15 to September-'15 as there is buzz going about release of Magento2. Below is the response i got by a Magento Cert. coordinator:

> We are still in the Beta testing stages of Magento 2, and will not
>   have an official release anytime soon.  We are suggesting that
>   everyone continue with taking the current certifications, as we cannot
>   formulate a new test for certifications until we actually have worked
>   out any bugs with Magento 2, which could take months.
>
> Since Magento 2 will be in Beta for quite a while, we will not be
>   adding it to our testing just yet!

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 Certifications won't be available in 2015, but, it could start somewhere in mid of 2016, but, previous version of exam will also in process.

- http://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/td-p/176
- http://www.slideshare.net/Magestorecom/does-magento-2-affect-the-result-of-magento-certification-this-year

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about Magento 2 now, it'll take a long time before appearing in Magento Certification test. I'm learning Magento as well. As far as i know there's no website provide the practice test (if you google there may be some sample questions elsewhere).